# Using Blazored.Modal, from a non-component class, should I expect a Modal dialog to appear when I call IModalService.Show<>?

Tags: dependency-injection, modal-dialog, blazor, blazor-component, blazored

Ordinarily when using Blazored.Modal, a Modal dialog appears when I call `IModalService.Show<>` from a component, when IModalService is injected, which works great.

Should I expect a Modal dialog to appear when I call  `IModalService.Show<>` from a method in a plain old C# class that is injected into a component (where IModalService is of course injected via the constructor)?  The method is called from the component, of course.

I couldn't imagine why it wouldn't--after all, the runtime is injecting the same IModalService into both, right?  But it does not and I don't understand why not.  Do you?

```cs
using Blazored.Modal.Services;
namespace ...;
public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    public Class1(IModalService modal)
    {
        Modal = modal ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modal));
    }
    protected IModalService Modal { get; set; }

    public void Show()
    {
        Modal.Show<MyDialog>();
    }
}
```

Then, from the component:

```
@using Blazored.Modal.Services;
@inject IClass1 class1;
@inject IModalService modal;
<button @onclick="class1.Show" >Show it</button> @* doesn't work *@
<button @onclick="@() => modal.Show<MyDialog>()" >Show it</button> @* works *@
```

([Also asked here.](https://github.com/Blazored/Modal/discussions/457))

Comment: How did you register the IClass1 service?

Comment: In Program.cs, `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IClass1, Class1>();` .  (This is Blazor WebAssembly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your scenario. When I tried to consume `IModalService` from a singleton service I got the following error:

> Cannot consume scoped service 'Blazored.Modal.Services.IModalService'
> from singleton 'BlazorWebAssembly.Client.Services.IMyModalService'.

After changing my service to scoped everything worked as expected and I was able to show modals.

Comment: You are right, that works perfectly.  Any idea why the Singleton doesn't?

Comment: These articles could be helpful: https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-cannot-consume-scoped-service/, https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/